# Parse Out Elements of a String in a List To Create DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nested-lists

I'm brand new to Python so I hope this makes sense:

I've created a list from file names I've pulled using the os module.

The file names look like '### Name 00.00', so there are integers, words, and floats all mixed into single strings in my list. It looks like this:

```
files_list = ['### File1 00.00','### File2 00.00','### File3 00.00']
```

I really need it to look something like:

```
files_list = [['###','File1','00.00'],['###','File2','00.00'],['###','File3','00.00']]
```

That way I can create a dataframe with the columns "Invoice #", "Vendor" , "Amount".

However, all I've been able to figure is to create a nested list with each string, so:

```
files_list = [files[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(files), 1)]

#which returns this format:
files_list = [[### File1 00.00],[### File2 00.00],[### File3 00.00]]
```

I'm sure there's a super simple solution, but I just don't know exactly how to ask the question in google.

TYIA

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

labels = ["Invoice #", "Vendor", "Amount"]

files_list = ["### File1 00.00", "### File2 00.00", "### File3 00.00"]

pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict(zip(labels, x.split(" "))) for x in files_list)
```

result:

```
  Invoice # Vendor Amount
0       ###  File1  00.00
1       ###  File2  00.00
2       ###  File3  00.00
```

Comment: Yes, good spot.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect! I have a question though: it randomly deleted the floats from 6 of my files with the same vendor, even though the amount is shown in the list. Any clue on this?

Comment: check your whitespace character x.split(" ") which we use to split on, should be consistent as in your example. Else post another question with the data we can reproduce and we'll have a look.

Comment: The file names had extra space. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To make list of lists do this

```
[file.split(', ') for file in files_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```py
pd.Series(files_list).str.split().tolist()
```

produces:

```py
[['###', 'File1', '00.00'],
 ['###', 'File2', '00.00'],
 ['###', 'File3', '00.00']]
```